# How to monitor the InputStream for '\n' in android

Tags: android

I need to monitor an `InputStream` for '\n'. Once the '\n' is found at the end of the `InputStream`, the code will return all the `InputStrea`m buffer back to UI. I have tried several methods without luck.

Here is my pseudo code.

```
public void run() {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    int bytes;

    // Keep listening and till InputStream has '\n'

    try {
        while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream some code here to check the occurrence of '\n';
            break;
        }
        SystemClock.sleep(1);

        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

    } catch (IOException e) {
       // Some code here to handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your exact need, wrapping the InputStream in a BufferedReader which provides a readLine() method might or might not help you.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion.